# Fit different image sizes to buttons

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So I am trying to create a row with buttons. Each button will have an image (which is a png with transparency) and because they have different sizes I am having different behavious on my buttons. This is what happened so far:

- Using Row with TextButton the button size will vary depending on the size of the image.
- Using a Row > Sized Box > TextButton I get same size buttons, but the image looks small on some of them, since they have different sizes.

Is there a reliable way to "increase" the image inside the button so they all fit correctly?   I tried just adding to the height, but nothing happened.

This was my latest attempt (Where buttons are the same size but images inside vary and height didn't make any difference):

```
SizedBox(
  height: 50,
  child: TextButton(
      onPressed: () => null,
      child: ColorFiltered(
          colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
              Colors.grey, BlendMode.modulate),
          child: Image.asset(
            'images/myimage.png',
            height: 100,
          ))),
),
```

Sorry, I'm quite new to Flutter so I hope I managed to explain correctly

---

Update 1: Here's the full code with the Container suggestion used in different ways:

```
class _DetailsPageState extends State<DetailsPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.red.shade300,
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Row(children: [
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 50,
                          child: TextButton(
                            onPressed: () => null,
                            child: Image.asset('images/shiny-stars.png'),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            image: DecorationImage(
                                image: AssetImage(
                                  'images/shiny-stars.png',
                                ),
                                fit: BoxFit.fill),
                          ),
                          // child: Image.asset('images/shiny-stars.png'),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 50,
                          child: TextButton(
                            onPressed: () => null,
                            child: ColorFiltered(
                              colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                                  Colors.green, BlendMode.modulate),
                              child: Container(
                                //width: _width,
                                height: 50,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: AssetImage(
                                      'images/shiny-stars.png',
                                    ),
                                    fit: BoxFit
                                        .fill, //filled the Image (size of Container)
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ]),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

- The first item (Row, is the one displaying the image but not covering much of the button),
- Second is the Container with BoxFit.fill which can't be seen in the screen
- Third is the SizedBox + Container, which makes the image disappear
  [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display images using `decoration` of `Container Widget`.
-Image Size
`BoxFit.contain` - original size
`BoxFit.cover` - Keep the aspect ratio to fill
`BoxFit.fill` - fill the specified area

```
GestureDetector(
 onTap: () => null,
 child: ColorFiltered(
   colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
      Colors.green, BlendMode.modulate),
   child: Container(
            width: 80,
            height: 50,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
               image: DecorationImage(
                         image: AssetImage(
                           image_path,
                         ),
                         fit: BoxFit.fill,
                         ),
                      ),
               ),
           ),
    ),
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, sadly didn't work (unless I did something wrong) I added the full code in the question to see if gives a better picture :(

Comment: Please add an image of the desired result

Comment: @Icaroto 
Edited the answer. Are you getting the results you want?

Comment: The new suggestion worked perfectly! Thanks @Jungwon !

Answer (score 0):

I think I found "a" solution

```
SizedBox(
  height: 40,
  child: ColorFiltered(
      colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
          Colors.grey, BlendMode.modulate),
      child: Image.asset('images/myimage.png')),
),
```

By removing the Button widget, the SizedBox height allow me to increase the picture size as I seem fit. The downside is that each element in the row will have a different size picked manually to make it look "aligned" with each other